# Spring reactor kafka - Handle failures by disconnecting and reconnecting with an exponential backoff

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux

What is the best way to handle failures by disconnecting and reconnecting from kafka with an exponential backoff in case of failure.
The idea is to let messages uncommited and reprocess them when the process reconnect after a certain time.

In akka stream, I can do that :

```java
RestartSource
        // Restart source will restart the stream if it fail 
        .onFailuresWithBackoff(RestartSettings.create(
                minBackoff, maxBackoff, 0)
                        .withMaxRestarts(maxRestart, minBackoff),
        () -> 
                // When the stream start it connect to kafka 
                Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
                    .map(mess -> 
                            //...do something
                            mess
                    )    
                    .watchTermination((control, done) -> {
                        done.whenComplete((d, e) -> {
                            // Disconnect from kafka when the stream is finished 
                            control.shutdown();
                        });
                        return control;
                    })
        );
```

How could I do that with spring reactor and reactor kafka ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer creating a `RestartSource` without any `Flow` and use `decider` to skip problematic element/message.

```
object TestStream {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("ActorService")

  val decider: Supervision.Decider = { e =>
    logger.error("Unhandled exception in stream.", e)
    Supervision.Resume
  }

  val finiteSource = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

  val settings = RestartSettings(
    minBackoff = 5.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2
  ).withMaxRestarts(20, 5.minutes)

  val source = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(settings) {
    () => finiteSource
  }

  val flow1 = Flow[Int].map(number => {
    number * 2
  })

  val flow2 = Flow[Int].mapAsyncUnordered(2)(number => {
    if (number == 4) {
      Future.failed(new RuntimeException("4 is not acceptable!"))
    } else {
      Future.successful(number * 4)
    }
  })

  val sink = Sink.onComplete {
    case Success(done) => logger.warn(s"Stream ended with result=$done")
    case Failure(ex) => logger.error(s"Stream ended with error=${ex.getMessage}", ex)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    source
      .via(flow1)
      .via(flow2)
      .toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
      .withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(decider))
      .run()
  }

}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what my code is doing. The idea is not to skip messages depending on a throwable but to retry uncommited messages for exemple when the database is not available.